# How to do a full outer join / merge of iterators by key?

Tags: python, functional-programming, iterator, generator

I have multiple sorted iterators that yield keyed data, representable by lists:

```
a = iter([(1, 'a'), (2, 't'), (4, 'c')])
b = iter([(1, 'a'), (3, 'g'), (4, 'g')])
```

I want to merge them, using the key and keeping track of which iterator had a value for a key. This should be equivalent to a full outer join in SQL:

```
>>> list(full_outer_join(a, b, key=lambda x: x[0]))
[(1, 'a', 'a'), (2, 't', None), (3, None, 'g'), (4, 'c', 'g')]
```

I tried using `heapq.merge` and `itertools.groupby`, but with `merge` I already lose information about the iterators:

```
>>> list(heapq.merge(a, b, key=lambda x: x[0]))
[(1, 'a'), (1, 'a'), (2, 't'), (3, 'g'), (4, 'c'), (4, 'g')]
```

So what I could use is a tag generator

```
def tagged(it, tag):
    for item in it:
        yield (tag, *x)
```

and merge the tagged iterators, group by the key and create a dict using the tag:

```
merged = merge(tagged(a, 'a'), tagged(b, 'b'), key=lambda x: x[1])
grouped = groupby(merged, key=lambda x: x[1])
[(key, {g[0]: g[2] for g in group}) for key, group in grouped]
```

Which gives me this usable output:

```
[(1, {'a': 'a', 'b': 'a'}),
 (2, {'a': 't'}),
 (3, {'b': 'g'}),
 (4, {'a': 'c', 'b': 'g'})]
```

However, I think creating dicts for every group is quite costly performance wise, so maybe there is a more elegant way?

Edit:

To clarify, the dataset is too big to fit into memory, so I definitely need to use generators/iterators.

Edit 2:

To further clarify, a and b should only be iterated over once, because they represent huge files that are slow to read.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? Feel free to post your own solution, or accept one of the below if they helped.

Comment: I have a solution but I didn't implement it yet, I will post it as soon as I have it. Cheers =)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution via dictionaries. I provide it here as it's not clear to me that dictionaries *are* inefficient in this case.

I believe `dict_of_lists` can be replaced by an iterator, but I use it in the below solution for demonstration purposes.

```
a = [(1, 'a'), (2, 't'), (4, 'c')]
b = [(1, 'a'), (3, 'g'), (4, 'g')]

dict_of_lists = {'a': a, 'b': b}

def gen_results(dict_of_lists):
    keys = {num for k, v in dict_of_lists.items() \
                for num, val in v}
    for key in keys:
        d = {k: val for k, v in dict_of_lists.items() \
                    for num, val in v if num == key}
        yield (key, d)
```

**Result**

```
list(gen_results(dict_of_lists))

[(1, {'a': 'a', 'b': 'a'}),
 (2, {'a': 't'}),
 (3, {'b': 'g'}),
 (4, {'a': 'c', 'b': 'g'})]
```

Comment: He is trying to avoid dicts for each group.

Comment: @StephenRauch, agreed. I added a comment to reflect this fact.

Comment: While this is indeed convenient, it loads the whole dataset into memory. I am looking for a solution using generators.

Comment: @membranepotential, Surely your "usable output" requires a whole new dataset in memory? Grouping methods will add an extra level of complexity.

Comment: To show the output, I needed to put in it a list, but you could exchange the `[(key, {g[0]: g[2] for g in group}) for key, group in grouped]` with `((key, {g[0]: g[2] for g in group}) for key, group in grouped)` and it would be a generator expression

Comment: @membranepotential, understood. Thanks for updating your question.

Comment: Updated to a generator version.

Comment: Thanks for coming back! :) I agree with you that dicts might be the cleanest solution with acceptable performance. Maybe even best performance ;-). However your code does not run, could you give it another glance over? I tried but can't figure out what `return nums` is supposed to do

Comment: I ran it just now (copied-pasted from my post), where do you see an error? `return_nums` just returns 1, 2, 3, 4.. so we know what `keys` are for the next function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167060/discussion-between-membranepotential-and-jpp).

Answer (score 2):

You can alter your `groupby` solution by using `reduce` and a generator in a function:

```
from itertools import groupby
from functools import reduce
def group_data(a, b):
   sorted_data = sorted(a+b, key=lambda x:x[0])
   data = [reduce(lambda x, y:(*x, y[-1]), list(b)) for _, b in groupby(sorted_data, key=lambda x:x[0])]
   current = iter(range(len(list(filter(lambda x:len(x) == 2, data)))))
   yield from [i if len(i) == 3 else (*i, None) if next(current)%2 == 0 else (i[0], None, i[-1]) for i in data]

print(list(group_data([(1, 'a'), (2, 't'), (4, 'c')], [(1, 'a'), (3, 'g'), (4, 'g')])))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 'a', 'a'), (2, 't', None), (3, None, 'g'), (4, 'c', 'g')]
```

Comment: Nice creativity here! +1 Three notes though. **(1)** It'd be better to have `group_data` accept the data is operates on as arguments, rather than hard-coding the data values. **(2)** In the OP's example, the `None` in the `3` tuple is the 1st item, while in your code the `None` is the 2nd. I'm not really sure this is a problem, just letting you know. **(3)** Your code is a bit hard to read. I suggest breaking the solution down into more steps.

Comment: While this looks indeed very nice, with this I lose information about which iterator supplied the data (as Christian explained in (2)). Using plain reduce is something i haven't thought about before though, maybe this is the key to a solution.

Comment: @membranepotential Can you clarify on how `None`'s position should be obtained? That is not immediately clear from your code.

Comment: @ChristianDean Thanks! (1) is fixed, and I am currently waiting for the OP's feedback regarding `None`. (3) is hopefully an improvement.

Comment: Sure: the tuple should have the key in the first position and None or the data at the positions according to which they have been supplied to the group_data function: so the result would be like `[ (a[0] or b[0], a[1] or None, b[1] or None) ]`. See also the alternative output.

Comment: Also I believe `sorted` needs to load the data into memory to sort it. Because the input data is already sorted, I think it should be unnecessary to concatenate and sort it again.

Comment: @membranepotential `sorted` needs to be applied for `groupby` to work properly. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @ChristianDean Good idea, please see my recent edit.

Comment: Okay @Ajax1234, got you. I'll just leave the rest of the discussion between you and the OP now.